# how do i draw a rectangle off the range of the cell while mouse is over the cell in c# datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

[my datagridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wi2GS.jpg)
use CellPainting event. 
I want to make a rectangle up there cell2.

```
 if (e.RowIndex >= suIndex1)
 {
     if (e.ColumnIndex == 7 || e.ColumnIndex == 8)
     {
         Point cursorPosition = this.dataOder.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
         if (e.CellBounds.Contains(cursorPosition))
         {
             Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 2f);
             Rectangle a = new Rectangle(col4.X, col4.Y, widthSum, e.CellBounds.Height - 1);

             e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, a);
             e.Handled = true;
          }
      }
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wi2GS.jpg)

Comment: I may be mistaken, but what you describe sounds more like a “CellMouseEnter” event as opposed to the “CellPainting” event.

Comment: CellPainting is only for one cell. This event is called for each Cell separately! Set some indicator flag to notify the other cell or a condidition, may referring to the current cell and handle it in the CellPainting event.

Comment: thank you. but i can not understand your comments. can i show the code as an example?